# How to use ffmpeg to stream x11 via netcat?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, netcat, mplayer

These are the commands I'm trying to use

Server side:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+10,20 -f avi - | nc -l 1500
```

Client side:

```
nc <server ip> 1500 | mplayer -vo x11 -cache 3000 -
```

It seems to be streaming on the server side but client is not able to view the stream.

Comment: You should also include the complete console output for each command.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the server and client confused; try on *sending* side:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+10,20 -f avi - \
| nc <server ip> 1500
```

and on the *receiving* side:

```
nc -l 1500 | mplayer -vo x11 -cache 3000 -
```